# How to do optional arguments that may be file names containing spaces

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'll spare you the entire multi-line `duplicity` command, but what I want to know is if it's possible is to tidy up a series of arguments in a script like this:

```
--exclude "$2/${4:-__nosuchfiles__}" --exclude "$2/${5:-__nosuchfiles__}" ...
```

the key thing is that `$4`, `$5`,... are names which often contain spaces. The present formulation works, but at the expense of those ugly defaults to `__nosuchfiles__` to exclude nothing if the set of exclusion criteria is smaller than the number of excludes passed. It's also a hack in that somebody conceivably might create a folder called `__nosuchfiles__`, and that there is a limit on the number of exclusions that it can handle.

What I'd like, is to define

```
EXCLUDES='--exclude "Path 1" --exclude "Path 2"'
```

with as many `--exclude` as I need, none to lots, and then substitute `$EXCLUDES` into a duplicity command line like:

```
duplicity $STUFF $EXCLUDES $SOURCE $DESTINATION
```

of course, it doesn't work when the excludes specify names containing spaces, and I can't work out any formulation for defining and using such a set of exclusions in the script itself. (Bonus points if any answer also handles `EXCLUDES=""` to mean no excludes at all. )

Yes, I know I could use duplicity's `--exclude-filelist`, but I'd like to know if there is a general solution that does not depend on the command conveniently being able to read a list of names from a file instead of from the command line. Note also the prefixing of `$2/` to all exclusion paths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the duplicity command line using an array rather than simple string concatenation. Then you can use the `"${array[@]}"` syntax to provide the contents of the array to duplicity as individual (possibly space-containing) arguments. This gets you out of the business of having to think about escaping spaces or other unusual characters.

To see how this works without actually calling duplicity, you could use a simple script that prints out its arguments on separate lines, such as this:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "BEGIN\n"

for x in "$@"
do
  printf "ARG: $x\n"
done

printf "END\n"
```

I've saved that as `args.sh`.

Now, we need to build a command using an array, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -z "$1"
then
  printf "Need at least one argument"
  exit 1
fi

prefix=$1
shift

for arg in "$@"
do
    args+=("--exclude")
    args+=("$prefix/$arg")
done

./args.sh "${args[@]}"
```

In action, this works as follows:

```
$ ./801811.sh foo bar "baz quux"
BEGIN
ARG: --exclude
ARG: foo/bar
ARG: --exclude
ARG: foo/baz quux
END
```

You'll need to do more to set up your duplicity command line, since you also need to account for `$STUFF` and `$DESTINATION`, but these can be handled in the same way by adding elements to the args array with `args+=("whatever")`, either before or after you add the exclusions, as appropriate. Then at the end, just call `duplicity "${args[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are a red herring here since the expansion is within quotes. If we call a program from the shell like this:

```
program "$foo_path/$bar_name"
```

it receives a single argument, no matter what `foo_path` or `bar_name` contain.

Now let's take a look at:

```
--exclude "$2/${4:-__nosuchfiles__}"
```

Here, you want to erase the entire argument pair if `4` is blank or doesn't exist, yielding the solution:

> `${4:+--exclude} ${4:+"$2/$4"}`

The `:+` parameter substitution operator is what you need: "if this is blank or unset, substitute nothing, otherwise substitute an alternative". We apply this individually to the `--exclude` and its argument.

Tools which use a `getopt` implementation (or otherwise hack the support themselves) can take both `--exclude=ARG` as well as `--exclude ARG`. If `duplicity` works this way, we can take advantage of it:

> `${4:+"--exclude=$2/$4"}`

Complete demo program `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

myargs()
{
  for x in "$@" ; do printf "<%s>\n" "$x"; done
}

myargs ${1:+--foo-opt} ${1:+"x $1 x"}
```

Runs:

```
$ ./test.sh
$ ./test.sh ""      # blank treated like missing?
$ ./test.sh abc
<--foo-opt>
<x abc x>
$ ./test.sh "ab c"
<--foo-opt>
<x ab c x>
```